# Can a service receive its own broadcasts?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

If I had a service called MyService and it looked like this, will the service's BroadcastReceiver recieve its own broadcast from the "sendData" method ??

What I am basically asking is is there going to be a problem if I used the same IntentFilter `Constants.SERVICE` of the broadcast receiver as an Intent Action to send broadcasts to my activity ?

**MyService.java**

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    private FFmpegMediaPlayer mp;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.SERVICE));
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void sendData() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.SERVICE);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there won't be any issue.

Comment: why are you trying to do such a thing...There wont be any issue

Comment: Oh thanks that good to hear, I just was afraid that errors happen if the service received its own broadcasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Adil Soomro** and **rupesh jain** mentioned it apparently won't be a problem as the service cannot receive it's own broadcasts.

#### EDIT

Actually after experimenting with it I found that the service can receive its own broadcasts if the `BroadcastReceiver` had the same `IntentFilter` as the broadcast intent.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly try this, but it seems completely unnecessary.  Bear in mind that what you're proposing is not for a service to receive its own broadcast (services don't receive any broadcasts), but you're define a broadcast receive *inside* the service and that is what receives the broadcast.

If you are trying to communicate between components, it's probably better to use LocalBroadcastManager, or some kind of event bus, because your broadcasts are going to all apps that could be listening, not just this one app.